# How to view device driver source files

Tags: linux-device-driver, kernel-module, beagleboneblack, debian-buster, kbuild

Hello i want to learn how to write device drivers so i figured i should check out some of the driver source files for i2c,spi,usb, etc. I did some searching to see if anyone else had a similar issue and i used the info found in this stack overflow question:

[Study device driver source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680905/study-device-driver-source-files)

After following the advice listed there i navigated to the following directory to view my drivers source files:

```
cd /lib/modules/4.19.94-ti-r42/build/drivers/
```

from the files listed here i was able to notice the i2c directory so i went into it thinking i would find the device driver source files for i2c. In this particular directory i have the following files:

```
algos  busses  Kconfig  Makefile  muxes
```

Within the each file there are more Kconfig files. I cant seem to find the source code for the drivers. I thought  the Kconfig files would hold the source code but looking inside them shows something different, its definitely not a c program. Does anybody know how i can recover the source code for the drivers on my system? I am currently using Debian 10 on a beagle bone black. Thanks

Comment: This is special build package which has only build infrastructure to create modules for the installed kernel. You rather need to download kernel sources from Git. And for the record, *drivers/i2c/...* contains drivers for I2C **host** controllers (master or slave mode), **muxes** and **algorithms**. I don't think this is a good start for a newbie, but it all depends to how deep you want to dive.

Comment: You can view source code of your kernel here - https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9.94/source/drivers/i2c .  You can also clone source code from kernel.org - https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git